# SPI and I2C Protocol Detection in Qt

Tags: qt, protocols, i2c, spi

I have made a logic analyzer board and transport it's data trough USB to PC. In the PC side, I have a Qt App to Receive data. My Question is: How to analyze Protocols like SPI, I2C, etc in my Qt App to find ACK, NAK and more? Is there any proper Library for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

you can access SPI via the bcm2835-library:   http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/bcm2835/
The RPi used this one. RPi had mostly bcm2836, later the bcm2837 (just like RPi3).

Comment: Dear @javad_, I haven't worked with I2C (via Raspberry Pi), but - as far as I have read - you can read/write to these devices by using the mapped files. Please search yourself via "i2c-tools". Greetings.